# Keep data altered from afterFind from updating that way?

Tags: php, cakephp

If I was using a `model`'s `afterFind` function to adjust the data based on their GEO location like so:

```
 #app/models/product.php
function afterFind($results) 
{
    if( $userInArea)
    {
        if(!isset($results[0]['Product']['price']))
        {
            return $results;    
        }
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) 
        {  
            $results[$key]['Product']['price'] = $this->priceAdjustAfterFind($val['Product']['price']);
        }

        return $results;
    }
}

function priceAdjustAfterFind($price) 
{    
    return $price * 1.2;
}
```

This would make the price field of the data returned by the model 20% higher if in a certain area.

The problem is:

Lets say the price is 100. An admin is in the GEO area and goes to edit a product `admin/product/edit/4`. The data given to the `edit view` from the `product model` will have the price increased to 120 because she is in the GEO area and will trigger the price adjust.

So as soon as she saves (say she adjusted the name) she will inadvertently change the price from 100 to 120. Now if she edits it again it will load as 144, increasing everytime.

I am not coming up with a logical way to prevent this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code need refactoring, Conditional update of price field is not a great idea.

```
$results[$key]['Product']['price_adjusted'] 
     = $this->priceAdjustAfterFind($val['Product']['price']);
```

Make a view helper

```
<?php
class PricingHelper extends AppHelper {
    function show($result) {
          return ($result['price_adjusted']) ? $result['price_adjusted'] : $result['price']
    }
}
```

In your view call

```
<?php echo $this->Pricing->show($result);  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to this is to store the *markup price* in the database as a separate field. This would avoid the problem you are having on edit as the user would always be editing the *base price*. This would also allow for the *markup price* to be calculated on the `save()` instead of every `find()`. This is much easier to control than your current method, which can be seen in multi-model finds.

The drawback of this approach is that it is not as dynamic as the `find()` method. Meaning that if your GEO markup changed, you'd have to resave each product for the price to update.

In the end, maybe some kind of hybrid works best for you. Either way, you could use a virtual field for *markup price* either in the model or one you set at runtime. This way you are not overwriting `price` and can still use it.

```
$results[$key]['Product']['markup_price'] = $this->priceAdjustAfterFind($val['Product']['price']);
```